webDetection Limited Number of Results
I'm aware of the default maxResults being set to 10. When I set the results to something like 9000, I'm still only getting back around 100 pagesWithMatchingImages. When I search the same image with Google Lens, I get a ton of results back. How do I increase the number of results returned from webDetection? Here is my request:
const response = await axios.post(
      'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate',
      {
        requests: [
          {
            features: [
              {
                type: 'WEB_DETECTION',
                maxResults: 9000,
                model: 'builtin/latest'
              }
            ],
            image: {
              content: base64Image
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'x-goog-user-project': PROJECT_ID,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }
    )

I get the same results back when using the client library too. Any help is appreciated!
I have tried the same request with both the client library and a Post request. The results seem to be limited. I've tried using maxResults at 500, 1000, 9000, 9999. It all comes back with only about 100 results. I'd like to have the same number of results as when I use google lens image search.
